# Django ORM - Subquery slower than two separate Queries

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have two models like that:

```
class MyDevice(models.Model):
    device_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    insert_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class MyDeviceMeasurement(models.Model):
    device_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    insert_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) -> Indexed
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    parent_device = models.ForeignKey(MyDevice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False,
    data = JSONField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Data from device")
```

Now, i want to do a subquery that annotate to the `MyDevice` model the latest measurement `data` property from the `MyDeviceMeasurement` table.

So, i've tried to follow the official Django Docs, that talks about [subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) and i've implemented the following query:

```
MyDevice.objects.annotate(
        latest_measurement=Subquery(
            MyDeviceMeasurement.objects.filter(parent_device=OuterRef('device_id')).order_by(
                '-insert_time').values('data')[:1]))
```

But, unfortunately, the query is VERY, VERY slow (the `MyDeviceMeasurement` queryset counts milions of rows): 57 seconds to complete.

Instead, using a simple python foor loop for every `MyDevice` and getting the latest `MyDeviceMeasurement` object by ordering by date, it's very fast, something like 20 milliseconds per device, in total, for 10 devices circa, it takes around 120 milliseconds.

This is very strange, and i'm not able to figure out why.

########UPDATE

Using this approach (Multiple queries), i've been able to issue a workaround for the problem, but, in any case, using the Subquery/Join approach, the issue persist, even if i add some new indexes, rebuild them, etc...

```
 result_list = []

    for smartdev in MyDevice.objects.all():
        try:
            latest_measurement = smartdev.data_set.latest()
            smartdev.latest_measurement = latest_measurement.data
        except MyDeviceMeasurement.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        result_list.append(smartdev)
```

Really, i can't figure why!

Comment: What if you add a `parent_device_id__isnull=False` filter in the subquery?

Comment: Nothing to do, slow like the old one...

Comment: what if you `index_together` the `parent_device` and `insert_time`.

Comment: Do you, by any chance `.filter(..)`, the `MyDevice`s?

Comment: What do you mean?